# Round decimal for a float number

Tags: c++, visual-c++, integer, cocos2d-x-3.0

in VC++ I have a float number say 1.32544354353
i.e `float num=1.32544354353;`
I want only first 1 digit after point. i.e 1.3 (not 1.300000000).
How can I get this?
Please help me...
If their is a solution in Cocos2dx thats better(I want this in my cocos2d-x game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what type do you want the result to be.

If you want to obtain the result as `float`, then this is impossible. From `float`'s point of view, 1.3 and 1.300000000 are exactly the same values and you can not have a `float` that holds 1.3, not 1.300000000. What you can do here is to drop extra digits by using, e.g., `(int)(val*10)/10.0`. (However, the float number precision problems will not make the results exactly 1.3, it will be something line 1.2999999982 or 1.3000000029 with some random digits at the end.)

If you want a string (meaning a string in general) representation, then you can gen a *string* `"1.3"`. To obtain this, use precision specifiers 
such as `"%.1f"` or `std::setprecision(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to display it in a Cocos2dx Label. So it is better to output as a std::string. How can I assign "%.1f"  for std::string variable please?

Comment: @Tony, for `std::string` output the better way will be to use `std::stringstream` and `std::setprecision(1)`, not `"%.1f"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
float val=1.32544;
float num=(float)(((int)(val*10))/10.0);
```

but beware of the overflow.

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting the value of num as 1.29999995!

Comment: Thats the problem of the precision of float. The Line 'float val2 = 1.3;' also results to 1.29995. You have to use double.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <math.h>

float x= 1.32544354353;
float f = roundf(x* 10) / 10;
```

If you just want to print it then you can simply use the format specifier like this:

```
("%.1f", 1.32544354353);
```

or

```
double d = 1.32544354353;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << d << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks. But not getting as expected. The answer of f is 1.29999995 .

Comment: @Tony:  That is due to the quirks of floating point representation. You can try to use the last wau which I have answered or else use double.

Comment: @Tony:- Here is a good read: [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

first thing that comes in my mind is that you can multiplay this by 10 (you will get 13) then cast this to int (so no more numbers after dot) and then divide this by 10 to float (you will get 1.3)

Answer (score -1):

```
char str[50];
sprintf(str, "%.1f",1.324567);
```

now str have a string 1.3

Comment: Well, that is not strictly rounding, you are converting to a string. What would you do in order to have a floating value?